# mathematical expression for arithmetic sequence with 3 variables where 1 of them is known

Tags: systems-of-equations, arithmetic, arithmetic-progressions

This is from an A-level exam paper, so it's fairly elementary. I'd like the know how to express the following mathematically.

> A construction programme began in 1986 and finished in 2010.
> The number of houses built each year form an arithmetic sequence, in year 2000, 238 houses are built. in year 2010, 108 houses are built.

My attempt to express this:

$$ a_{n-i} = a + (n-i)(d)$$ n=corresponding year, i=starting year

$$ a_n = f(n-i)$$

$$ f(2000-1986) = 238$$

$$f(2010-1986) = 108 $$

Can I leave $a$ and $d$ out like that?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, notice the trend first. In $2000$ we had $238$ houses and in $2010$ we had $108$ houses, so in $10$ years, the number of houses construction decreased by $108-238=130$, which means roughly $13$ houses every year. Now $1986$ is $14$ years before $2000$ so, $14*13=42$, so in $1986$, we will have $238+182=420$ houses!

Answer (score 0):

The general term of an arithmetic sequence with difference $d$ and first term $a_1$ is $a_n=a_1+(n-1)d$.

We have that $a_{15}$, corresponding to the year $2000$ is equal to $238$, and similarly that $a_{25}$, corresponding to the year $2010$ is equal to $108$, thus

$$a_{15}=a_1+(15-1)d=238\\a_{25}=a_1+(25-1)d=108$$

By solving this system you can directly compute $a_1, d$ and thus any $a_n$.

Answer (score -1):

An arithmetic sequence is generally written like so: $a_i = di + a_0$ where d is the Common Difference and $a_0$ is the Initial Term.

Your problem gives you that in 2000 there were 238 houses built, but only 108 houses were built in 2010. So $d = (108 - 238) / (2010 - 2000) = -13$.

To compute $a_0$ we simply plug d into the equation along with one of the data points. So $238 = -13(2000 -1986) + a_0$. Solve to get $a_0 = 420$ (if I did it in my head right).

So the formula would be $a_i = -13i + 420$. For i, plug-in the difference in years between the year in question and the initial year (1986).